# CasperJS waitUntilVisible by Xpath

Tags: xpath, casperjs, backstop.js

Just started working with CasperJS, writing a few sample tests.  Everything works fine when using CSS Selectors, however I'm having trouble using Xpath.  The only reason I want to use xpath is to create a more resilient locator, i.e.

`'//a[text()="Office Building"]'` versus the css version: `#content > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > a`

Here's what I've tried **(Note: I have tested this xpath in the browser console)**:

Tried passing directly

```
casper.waitUntilVisible('//a[text()="Office Building"]');
```

Tried specifying the locator explicitly as Xpath:

```
casper.waitUntilVisible({
    type: 'xpath',
    path: '//a[text()="Office Building"]'
});
```

And tried requiring the helper `selectXPath` from the module [as documented here](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html#index-2):

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.waitUntilVisible(x('//a[text()="Office Building"]'))';
```

All of these result in a timeout error `Wait timeout of 30000ms expired, exiting.` because the element is never "found".  Any ideas?

Comment: What about the "contains" version: `//a[contains(., "Office Building")]`?

Comment: Another optiion would be casper.waitForText('Office Building'). The last example you wrote should work, but better with contains in case of space.

Comment: @alecxe wow you're everywhere :) unfortunately same result.  I may try a few different methods, such as using `evaluate` to get into the DOM, and force some things there directly

Comment: @dasmelch unfortunately that won't help me too much, cause my next step is going to be `casper.click('//a[text()="Office Building"]');`  So it's really the locator that I need to figure out.

Comment: Can't you use another option than the inner html text, something like id, class or any other tag paramter? It's always better then the text. You can use @alecxe soltion for that, like //a[contains(@class, "office_building")] or //a[contains(@href, 'office_building')] or etc.?

Comment: @dasmelch It's a series of angular repeater elements, so they all have the same attributes.  I think text is the only unique thing about them =/

Comment: Ok got it. ;) And a casper.waitForText and casper.clickLabel doesn't do the job?

Comment: @dasmelch ah, I did not see the clickLabel method.  Combined with waitForText works for me!  If you want to write up a small answer I will accept that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution if you are only got text as identifier for waiting and clicking a link in casperjs without using xPath. 
It's more simple to wait for the text and then use clickLabel (if the text is unique):

```
casper.start('http://yourTestUrl.com');

casper.then(function() {
    casper.waitForText('Office Building');
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.clickLabel('Office Building');
});

casper.run();
```